# Connecting OpenERP with CodeIgniter XML RPC library

Tags: php, codeigniter, odoo, xml-rpc

I've the following [Codeigniter XML RPC](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/xmlrpc.html) code for searching customers in a OpenERP database,

I' following this [documentation](http://doc.openerp.com/v6.0/developer/6_22_XML-RPC_web_services/index.html#php) for implementing search
The below code works fine and retrieves the all the records in res.partner table

```
    $this->xmlrpc->server('http://localhost/xmlrpc/object',8314);
    $this->xmlrpc->method('execute');   
    //$this->xmlrpc->set_debug(TRUE);       

   $request = array (
           array($this->database, 'string'),
           array($this->userid , 'int'),
           array($this->password, 'string'),  
           array("res.partner", 'string'), 
           array('search', 'string'),
           array(array(), 'array'),
         ); 
   $this->xmlrpc->request($request);
   if ( ! $this->xmlrpc->send_request())
    {
        echo $this->xmlrpc->display_error();
        return -1;
    }
    else 
    {
        //print_r( $this->xmlrpc->display_response());
        $val = $this->xmlrpc->display_response();
        return $val;
    }
```

Now I want to get only the items with `name=abc`

```
    $this->xmlrpc->server('http://localhost/xmlrpc/object',8314);
    $this->xmlrpc->method('execute');   
    //$this->xmlrpc->set_debug(TRUE);       
    $attribute = "name";
    $operator = "=";
    $keys="abc";

    $key = array(
        new XML_RPC_Values(array(
            new XML_RPC_Values($attribute , "string"),
            new XML_RPC_Values($operator,"string"),
            new XML_RPC_Values($keys,"string"))
        ,"array"),
    );
   $request = array (
           array($this->database, 'string'),
           array($this->userid , 'int'),
           array($this->password, 'string'),  
           array("res.partner", 'string'), 
           array('search', 'string'),
           $key,
         ); 
   $this->xmlrpc->request($request);
   if ( ! $this->xmlrpc->send_request())
    {
        echo $this->xmlrpc->display_error();
        return -1;
    }
    else 
    {
        //print_r( $this->xmlrpc->display_response());
        $val = $this->xmlrpc->display_response();
        return $val;
    }
```

This is not working and it thowss the following errors

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Object of class XML_RPC_Values could not be converted to int
Filename: libraries/Xmlrpc.php
Line Number: 1216


A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: 4096
Message: Object of class XML_RPC_Values could not be converted to string
Filename: libraries/Xmlrpc.php
Line Number: 1360
```

the result is same all the records of the res.partner table is retrieved

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your error is on the PHP side before you send the request, not in the OpenERP server.

I'm not sure, but the nesting level of the `"array"` type string in your second code snippet looks wrong.

Here's a trimmed version of your first, working snippet:

```
       ...
       $request = array (
           ...
           array('search', 'string'),
           array(array(), 'array'),
       );
```

Now here's a version of your second, broken snippet where I inlined the `$key` variable and trimmed some other stuff:

```
       $request = array (
           ...
           array('search', 'string'),
           array(
               new XML_RPC_Values(
                   array(
                       new XML_RPC_Values($attribute , "string"),
                       new XML_RPC_Values($operator,"string"),
                       new XML_RPC_Values($keys,"string")
                   ),
                   "array"
               ),
           ),
       );
```

You're passing an `XML_RPC_Values` object as the only parameter to an array. Does PHP expect an integer length when you pass in one parameter? If it does, then this error message makes sense:

> Object of class XML_RPC_Values could not be converted to int

Is that outer XML_RPC_Values object even necessary?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is the problem I noticed that your "key" doesn't have a $. should be:

```
$request = array (
       array($this->database, 'string'),
       array($this->userid , 'int'),
       array($this->password, 'string'),  
       array("res.partner", 'string'), 
       array('search', 'string'),
       $key,
     );
```